# Unable to read some files found using os.walk

Tags: python, filesystems, python-os

I am unable to read handful of files in my computer using python. Most of the folders in the computer look ok, but 200 or so files in the whole computer can't be read.

Code on a high level is doing this

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\DR\SomeFolder'):
    for f in files:
        print(f, os.path.exists(root + os.sep + f))
```

`os.path.exists()` returns `False` for handful of files. Not sure why. I can't anything significantly different with these files or the directories.

I tried `os.path.join()` and `open()`. All of them fail to read the file.

Is it something weird like invisible characters or special characters in the file name or the directory?

Comment: does the user running this script have permissions to read those files?

Comment: It would help if you gave some examples of file paths to files you know must exist, but can't be read from your script.

Comment: Can you read/see the files by some file manager means? Is the behaviour between your script and say windows explorer the same?

Comment: fail to read the file? What's the error you're getting? post the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the user has permissions. I am running it as myself and is able to open the file in explorer

Comment: I can open in windows explorer.

Comment: Please don't use the answer section for answers to comments. Either answer in a comment or edit your question. Thanks!